# How to discount the percentage type with total price?

Tags: laravel

I need to discount with percentage type with a total price of the cart?

the prices:

```
total_cart: 11,000

discoutn(percentage): 10%
```

my shut:

```
if ($this->coupon->type === "percentage") {
   return $total_cart * ($this->coupon->value / 100);
}
```

With this code I got this result `1,100` |: !

Comment: Well, plug the numbers in and do the math. `11000 * (10 / 100)` Use that to figure out where the error in your math logic is. Right now, you're giving a 90% discount, not a 10% one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($this->coupon->type === "percentage") {
   return $total_cart * ((100-$this->coupon->value) / 100);
}
```

Comment: you want to get the 90%  ( 100% - 10% ) of your total. 

this would be the same (from your code) :  $total_cart - ( $total_cart * ($this->coupon->value / 100) )

Comment: that's mean (  ( 100 - 10 )  / 100 ) * total_cart ??